# Google Maps : How to remove mini preview?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What is that box and how to remove that?

Here is my code

```
  var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      panControl:false, 
      mapTypeControl:false, 
      scaleControl:false, 
      streetViewControl:false, 
      overviewMapControl:false,
      rotateControl:false 
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-map'),
             mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the center attribute did the thing for me.

```
var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      /*center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),*/
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      panControl:false, 
      mapTypeControl:false, 
      scaleControl:false, 
      streetViewControl:false, 
      overviewMapControl:false,
      rotateControl:false 
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-map'),
             mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```